# JUnit AssertionError - Expected exception not thrown

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm trying to familiarise myself with JUnit/Mockito and am using the below method to attempt some unit tests:

```
public FSDataInputStream getObj(String hName, Path p) throws IOException {

    String myKey = pathToKey(hName, p);
    FileStatus status = memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString());
    if (status == null) {
      status = getStatus(hName, p, "getObj");
    }
    if (status.isDirectory()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't open " + path
  + " because it is a directory");
    }
    InputStream inputStream = new InputStream(bucket, myKey,
    status.getLen(), client, readAhead, inputPolicy);

    return new FSDataInputStream(inputStream);
}
```

I wish to test that the fileNotFoundException is thrown if status.isDirectory == true.

I believe I must invoke the getObj() method and for `if (status.isDirectory())` I must ensure the value is true. I think this is done with `when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);` I'm not sure how to invoke the method and make sure this takes place.

So far I've got this JUnit but it doesn't seem to be correct as its returning the below error:

```
public class ClientTest {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = mock(MemoryCache.class);
    FileStatus fileStatus = mock(FileStatus.class);

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void getObjTest() throws Exception {
        Path path = new Path("xyz://aa-bb-cc/data7-1-23-a.txt");

        when(memoryCache.getFileStatus(path.toString())).thenReturn(fileStatus);
        when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);
        exception.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);
    }
}
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw an instance of java.io.FileNotFoundException
>       at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.failDueToMissingException(ExpectedException.java:263)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$200(ExpectedException.java:106)
>       at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:245)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>       at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Can anybody advise what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why did you comment the first when? seems to be the right choice

Comment: I commented it out when experimenting. I must have forgot to uncomment when I posted the query. Will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getObj` must be declared inside a class (we can't see that in the OP) but let's assume it is in this class:

```
public class Foo {
    private MemoryCache memoryCache;

    public Foo(MemoryCache memoryCache) {
        this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public FSDataInputStream getObj(String hName, Path p) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, your test could look like this:

```
public class ClientTest {
    private MemoryCache memoryCache = mock(MemoryCache.class);
    private FileStatus fileStatus = mock(FileStatus.class);

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void getObjTest() throws Exception {
        Path path = new Path("xyz://aa-bb-cc/data7-1-23-a.txt");

        // create the class-under-test, supplying the mocked MemoryCache
        Foo foo = new Foo(memoryCache);

        // establish your expectations on the mocked classes
        // for this test the expectations are:
        // - memoryCache returns the mocked fileStatus    
        // - the mocked fileStatus 'is a' directory        
        when(memoryCache.getFileStatus(path.toString())).thenReturn(fileStatus);
        when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);

        // you expect a FileNotFoundExceptionException ...
        exception.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);

        // ... when you invoke getObj
        foo.getObj("aString", path);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- You have to invoke `getObj` inside your test
- The `getObj` invocation has to enter the `if (status.isDirectory()) { ... }` block
- You have to instruct the mocked `MemoryCache` to return the mocked `FileStatus`
- You have to instruct the mocked `FileStatus` to return true when `isDirectory` is invoked
- You have to supply the mocked `MemoryCache` to the instance of `Foo` which is under-test, in the above example this is done by constructor injection

Comment: Thanks for the response @glytching. I used the first answer but can see this would work too.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Uncomment the first `when` statement as it is necessary for the next `when` set-up to work.

**2)** Invoke the method under test

**3)** (Optional) use annotations for mocking:

```
public class ClientTest {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private Client clientSpy = new Client();

    @Mock
    MemoryCache memoryCache;
    @Mock
    FileStatus fileStatus;

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    @Before
    public void init(){
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getObjTest() throws Exception {
       // Arrange
       Path path = new Path("xyz://aa-bb-cc/data7-1-23-a.txt");

        doReturn(Mockito.anyString()).when(clientSpy)
           .pathToKey(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());         

        when(memoryCache.getFileStatus(path.toString()))
           .thenReturn(fileStatus);

        when(fileStatus.isDirectory()).thenReturn(true);

        exception.expect(FileNotFoundException.class);

        // Act
        clientSpy.getObj(name, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your example but get a NullPointerError for the line `FileStatus status = memoryCache.getStatus(p.toString());`. Do I need to do anything else to ensure its not null?

Comment: ok, there is an additional pathToKey method at the beginning which you may need to mock.. by spying on the class under test. Also you need to inject the cache by supposedly using the InjectMocks

Comment: Finally got it. I didn't have the Spy and InjectMocks annotations. All working now. Thanks for the help.